# If every brother has one book, are they brothers' books or brothers' book?

Tags: grammatical-number, saxon-genitive

Let's assume I have two brothers, Cain and Abel. Cain has book A, Abel has book B. Should I call that books "my brothers' books" or "my brothers' book" to distinguish between having one book or more books?

Comment: "my brothers' book" implies joint ownership over one book. Go with `books`

Comment: This would be better asked on our sister English site, [ELL.se]. But the short answer is: there is more than one book, so you need the plural, *books*. Now, if Cain and Able had co-authored a book ("*The Principles of Harmonious Fraternity: The Development of Agriculture in the Age of Nomads*", say), then it would be proper to refer to that as "my brothers' book", singular. Though I certainly wouldn't want to be the one to arbitrate the royalty rights.

Comment: They are books of the brothers.

Comment: I am certain there are duplicate questions for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Let's assume I have two brothers, Cain and Abel. Cain has book A, Abel has book B. Should I call that books "my brothers' books" or "my brothers' book" to distinguish between having one book or more books?*

The question is not clear.  "That books" is the first confusion.

If you mean **those books** (book A and book B), plural, then they belong your brothers, plural, then:

- my brothers' books

If you mean a book that belongs to one brother, then:

- my brother's book

Distinguishing between one book (they each have one book) or two (the two of them together have two books), is a different matter.  If you mean one book, and you mean the brothers collectively, then:

- my brothers' book

If you mean one book, and you mean one brother, then:

- my brother's book

If you mean both books, which can only be both brothers collectively, then:

- my brothers' books

Answer (score 0):

Use 's if singularly own; s' if jointly owned.  For example, that is my "brother's business" if only one (of any quantity of brothers own the business) or that is "my brothers' business" if two or more Both own the business (or book) and those "are my brothers' businesses" if two each own businesses.